# Align all text (excluding section/list numbers)

Tags: indentation

I am attempting to align all of my text, with the exclusion of the section numbering and enumerate numbering, aligned at the same indent/vertical rule.  Basically, the section/list numbering would be all in one column and the text that accompanies it would be in another (though I don't believe the `multicol` environment would be ideal for this for many reasons).

This alignment follows the standard formatting for the document type I'm working on, hence the somewhat weird format.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in,bottom=1.5in,top=1.25in,head=1in]{geometry}

%----Change default LaTeX section styles---------------------------
\usepackage{titlesec} % Lets user adjust section header formatting

\renewcommand\thesection{25.\arabic{section}}   %Add "25." before section numbering
\setcounter{section}{-1}   %Set first section number to "0"

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength\parindent{0pt}   %no indent for all paragraphs

\begin{document}

\section[Introduction]{INTRODUCTION}

\subsection{Scope}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is Item 1.
    \item Oh look, another item!
    \item This is getting out of hand.
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

My MWE generates something like this:

[image]

But what I'm looking for is more like this:

[image: correct]

Comment: What happens for nested lists? Are there any?

Comment: @Werner, nested lists would have the same behavior (ex. Item 1, Subitem a would also have the "a" in the left margin space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution with `titlesec` and `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in,bottom=1.5in,top=1.25in,head=1in, showframe]{geometry}

\setlength\parindent{0pt} %no indent for all paragraphs
\usepackage{titlesec}
%Set first section number to "0"
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\llap{\makebox[0.6in][l]{\thesection}}}{0em}{\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\llap{\parbox{0.6in}{\thesubsection}}}{0em}{}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{labelwidth = \dimexpr0.6in-\labelsep, align = left, leftmargin = 0pt}
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{label=\alph*.}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{24}
\setcounter{section}{-1}
\section[Introduction]{Introduction}
\subsection{Scope}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is Item 1.
    \item Oh look,other items!
\begin{enumerate}%[label =\alph. ]
  \item A first subitem
\item Another subitem
\end{enumerate}
    \item This is getting out of hand.
\end{enumerate}
Lalala

\section{Another section}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please see the revised MWE.  I have a couple updates.

Comment: Please see the modified answer.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it still possible to alter the format of the section and subsection headers?  See my `\titleformat` changes in the MWE.

Comment: Do you obtaining the same result with the advanced interface of `titlesec`?

Comment: Changing the header format using `\titleformat` requires an argument for `<sep>` between the number and the header, which negates the coding you added with `\titlelabel`.  I'm not particularly well-versed in `titlesec` to make any additional changes using the Advanced Interface.

Comment: I've updated my answer (and improved it – there was a slight flaw: the enumerate labels were not exactly aligned with the section labels).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=2in,right=1in,bottom=1.5in,top=1.25in,head=1in]{geometry}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}   %no indent for all paragraphs
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\noindent\llap{\csname the#1\endcsname \quad}}
\leftmargini0pt

\begin{document}

\section[Introduction]{INTRODUCTION}

\subsection{Scope}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is Item 1.
    \item Oh look, another item!
    \item This is getting out of hand.
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

For left aligned section numbers:

```
\def\@seccntformat#1{\noindent\llap{\makebox[1in][l]{\csname the#1\endcsname}}}
```

or with a bit of help from `enumitem` left aligned list labels as well

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=2in,right=1in,bottom=1.5in,top=1.25in,head=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}   %no indent for all paragraphs
\makeatletter
%\def\@seccntformat#1{\noindent\llap{\csname the#1\endcsname \quad}}
\def\@seccntformat#1{\noindent\llap{\makebox[1in][l]{\csname the#1\endcsname}}}

\setlist{leftmargin=0pt,align=left,labelwidth=1in,labelsep=0pt}
\begin{document}

\section[Introduction]{INTRODUCTION}

\subsection{Scope}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is Item 1.
    \item Oh look, another item!
    \item This is getting out of hand.
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to align the numbers all of the left side?

Comment: er yes if you say how wide the widest one will be if you have sub sub section 100 of section 1000 do you need space for 1000.100.100.1 ?

Comment: your example had enumeration numbers flush right though (it seems) so just headings flush left?

Comment: The deepest it would go is probably 99.99.99.99, I think.

Comment: Enumeration also left-aligned. Sorry, on mobile now and can't update the image.

Comment: @grfrazee ah OK I'd just added left aligned sections, will add lists after that you are on your own:-)

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle, just tried out your solution and I'm having issues due to my reformatting of section numbering, as shown in the updated MWE.  Any chance you could revisit?