# Bibliography entry numbering to start with section number

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I'm attempting to make my bibliography numbering style begin with the section number followed by an arabic number for each entry.  For example:

```
25.7      REFERENCES

25.7.1    First Reference
25.7.2    Second Reference
```

Similar to my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361509/align-all-text-excluding-section-list-numbers) on aligning section headers, I would want the bibliography item numbers also in the left margin.

Here's my MWE, which has obvious issues.  This is as close as I can get.

```
\documentclass[letterpage,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=black,hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

%Set page margins
\usepackage[left=1.75in,right=1in,headheight=1in,bottom=1.5in,footskip=0.5in,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand\thesection{25.\arabic{section}}   %Add "25." before section numbering
\setcounter{section}{6}   %Set first section number to "7" for this MWE
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361509/align-all-text-excluding-section-list-numbers
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\llap{\makebox[0.75in][l]{\thesection}}}{0em}{\MakeUppercase}

\usepackage{etoolbox} %Patch bibliography style to it doesn't go to the next page
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}   %no indent for all paragraphs

\begin{document}

\section{References}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{} %Remove "Bibliography" header

\renewcommand\bibitem{25.\arabic{section}. }   %Add section number before reference numbering

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

    \bibitem{Reference 1}

    \bibitem{Reference 2}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I assume you're interested in using some kind of numeric style for citation call-outs. Should the citation call-outs continue to appear as `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. in the body of the document, or should they appear as `[25.7.1]`, `[25.7.2]`, etc?

Comment: Citations should appear `25.7.1` in the text, no brackets.

Comment: And if cited material is used twice in different sections, I guess it should get the number of the first section it was used in?!

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but there is only one References section in the entire document.

Comment: Oh. Now I think I get it... You just want them all to be 25.7.xx (where 25.7 is the section 'REFERENCES'). First I thought you wanted them to be numbered after the section they were cited in.

Comment: @Skillmon, correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by patching the internal command `\@bibitem`, which as standard uses only a simple list counter, and changing the `\@biblabel` command as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@bibitem}{\the\value{\@listctr}}{\thesection.\the\value{\@listctr}}{}{Bib patch failed}
\def\@biblabel#1{[\thesection.#1]}
\makeatother
```

Note that you have already loaded `etoolbox` and you have already set-up `\thesection` to produce the information you wish.  In the code below, I have removed much of your other formatting set-up that is not relevant to this problem.  Further to your comment, I have now added `hyperref` to show it works with this (you just need to be careful about the execution order) and have added further adjustments to the `bibliography` environment and `\@biblabel` so the labels are printed in the margin.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{report}

\renewcommand\thesection{25.\arabic{section}}

\setcounter{section}{6}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\leftmargin\labelwidth}{\leftmargin0pt}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\advance\leftmargin\labelsep}{}{}{}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@bibitem}{\the\value{\@listctr}}{\thesection.\the\value{\@listctr}}{}{Bib patch failed}
\def\@biblabel#1{\llap{[\thesection.#1]\ }}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\bibname}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Text}

\cite{R1} and \cite{R2}

\section{References}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{R1} Reference 1

\bibitem{R2} Reference 2
\end{thebibliography}

\section{More text}

\cite{S1,R1}

\section{More references}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{S1} Reference 3
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The above prints the labels right aligned followed by a space before the left margin.  If you wished to copy your section labelling style exactly then use the following definition for `\@biblabel` instead:

```
\def\@biblabel#1{\llap{\makebox[0.75in][l]{[\thesection.#1]}}}
```

Comment: This does work, but I realized that it conflicts with the `hyperref` package that I'm using if I don't load `hyperref` after your additions for the bib numbering.  However, it doesn't account for the margin spacing concerns I brought up via reference to my previous question.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Where you have `\labelwidth` as the width of the left margin, how would one change this to be 0.75in?  I have the section numbers in a 0.75in-wide margin in the rest of the document, and having the reference numbers align left with these is the desired effect.

Comment: You misunderstand, the `\labelwidth` is in code that is being deleted from the standard definition.  Anyway all you need is a different definition of `\@biblabel` now added to my answer at the end.